# Cursor fetch into return null values - Mysql

Tags: mysql, cursor, procedure

I'm having some problems with a cursor in a mysql procedure. It's not the first time I write a procedure using a cursor in Mysql but, this time, I'm not able to solve my problem.

Here is the code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE modifica_importi_fatt(IN numero_fatt VARCHAR(20),lavorazione VARCHAR(10),data_emissione_fatt VARCHAR(10))
BEGIN
    DECLARE idf1 INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE sql_create_tab_bck VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE var_idm VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT 'xxx';
    DECLARE finito BOOLEAN default FALSE;
    DECLARE var_imp_atteso DOUBLE DEFAULT 0.0;
    DECLARE var_idrow INT(10) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE var_impu FLOAT DEFAULT 0.0;
    DECLARE var_giorni INT DEFAULT 0;     

    DECLARE cur_dett_fatt cursor for
        (select dett_fatt.idm,tmp_fatt.importoatteso,dett_fatt.idrow,tmp_fatt.importounitario
            from dett_fatt, tmp_fatt,fatture 
                where dett_fatt.idm=tmp_fatt.idunicomov
                    and dett_fatt.idf1ura=fatture.idf1ura
                    and fatture.numerofattura=numero_fatt);

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finito = TRUE;

    SET @finito=FALSE;

    /* *** LAVORAZIONE EFFETTIVA */
IF(lavorazione='lav') THEN

        select idf1ura into @idf1 from fatture where numerofattura=numero_fatt; -- prelevo idf1ura della fattura che sto lavorando
        /* backup di dett_fatt per la fattura di cui si vanno a modificare gli importi */
        SET @sql_create_tab_bck=concat('CREATE TABLE dett_fatt_',@idf1,' as select * from dett_fatt where idf1ura=',@idf1);



        PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql_create_tab_bck;
        EXECUTE stmt1;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;                      

        OPEN cur_dett_fatt;
        loop_upd_dett: LOOP
        FETCH cur_dett_fatt INTO var_idm,var_imp_atteso,var_idrow,var_impu; 
        IF (finito) THEN LEAVE loop_upd_dett;
        END IF;

        select concat('Verifico variabile idm = ',@var_idm);


            UPDATE dett_fatt
                SET imponibile=@var_imp_atteso, iva=round((@var_imp_atteso*0.22),2), importounitario=@var_impu 
                where idm=@var_idm and idf1ura=@idf1 and idrow=@var_idrow;
        END LOOP;               

                COMMIT;                
CLOSE cur_dett_fatt;


/* *** PRE-LAVORAZIONE *** */               
ELSEIF (lavorazione='pre_lav') THEN

    DO something...

ELSE
    select 'parametro in input "lavorazione" non congruo. Può essere "pre_lav" (fase 1 della procedura) oppure "lav" (fase 2 della procedura)' as esito_proc;
END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I don't have problems creating the procedure, but it doesn't work well, cause the "FETCH INTO" returns null values, and so i'm not able to do the UPDATEs at the end. 
Has anyone had the same problem?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked if your newly created Table has any rows and without any data it is almost impossible to debug your code. so you have to do iz by yourself

Comment: `finito` and `@finito` are two different variables. First is declared variable, it has definite datatype and block scope. Second is user-defined variable, it has generic (not specified) datatype and it has connection scope. The same with another variables.

Comment: @Akina, thanks, your advice was right! i solved my problem :-)